# Usage of Upon in unusual way after verb and before noun

Tags: meaning

So I would like to ask if the usage of *upon* makes sense in the following sentence. I have already done extensive research on the interwebs but have not come to a conclusion; hence I am here.

Does this sentence make sense?

> Did the boy deliver the agreed upon resolution?

I don't believe the usage of *upon* makes sense in that sentence. 
If I'm wrong, how does that change the meaning from the following sentence?

> Did the boy deliver the agreed resolution?

Comment: The first sentence makes a lot more sense, and is a lot more idiomatic (i.e. phrased the way native speakers would typically phrase it) than the latter, which simply doesn't work.  You may wish to google the phrase "*agreed upon*" as a unit.

Comment: It's a compound in this usage, so [Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agreed+upon) doesn't even use the term 'adjectival phrase': **agreed upon** Adj. 1. ...  _constituted or contracted by stipulation or agreement_

Answer (score 3):

According to ODO the adjectival *[agreed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agreed)* is sufficient:

> *[adjective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agreed)*
>
> [ATTRIBUTIVE]
> 1.0 Discussed or negotiated and then accepted by all parties:
> *the agreed date*
>
> 1.1 (Of two or more parties) holding the same view or opinion on something:
> *all the republics are agreed on the necessity of a common defence policy*

[The Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/agree) concurs with added explanation:

> 3 of two or more people or groups : to decide to accept something
> after discussing what should or might be done
> [no object]
> — usually + *on* or *upon*
>
> - The jurors were unable to agree on a verdict. [=to reach a verdict]
> - agree on a plan
> - They agreed on a fair division of the profits.
>
> [+ object] (Brit)
>
> - The jurors were unable to agree a verdict.
> - The means of ending the dispute were finally agreed.
>
> ◊ The forms agreed, agreed-upon, and (less commonly) agreed-on are
> used as adjectives in both U.S. and British English.
>
> - She paid him the agreed price.
> - They met at the agreed-upon time.

*[Agreed upon](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agreed+upon)* is preferred in legal language for a binding contractual arrangement:

> constituted or contracted by stipulation or agreement; "stipulatory
> obligations"
>
> *WordNet 3.0 Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.*

The dominance of *[agreed upon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22agreed%20upon%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)* in the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=agreed%20_ADJ_%2Cagreed%20upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cagreed%20_ADJ_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagreed%20upon%3B%2Cc0), seems to be rooted in formal, regulatory and legal usage. The connotation of legal consistency may give native speakers a greater sense of accuracy with agreed upon.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, the term "*agreed upon*" is correct. Preferred, even. It's a tad formal and the phrase "*agreed on*" is also unambiguous. There is slight ambiguity when the boy delivers "*the agreed resolution*" in that it suggests mainly that the resolution was considered final by all concerned plus a small ambiguity that the resolution was one of agreement as to its internal terms.

As an "*agreed upon*" or "*agreed on*" resolution, the only agreement is that the final submitted resolution was agreed to, not that its internal particulars were made up of agreements, point by point.

If I were using the idea in poetry, "agreed resolution" might be better for the meter of the line. We need a solution to the agreed resolution.